# Youtube list search with cc filter?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the google-api-php-client to search youtube for videos and I want to filter the results to only return videos with captions(cc).

Is it possible? If yes, how should I modify the query?

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
));
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list see `videoCaption` ?

Comment: Thank you Scuzzy. That is exactly what I need. I added 'videoCaption' => 'closedCaption', It works!

Comment: I'll move my comment into an answer then

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

The API docs mention a `videoCaption` string parameter

> The videoCaption parameter indicates whether the API should filter video search results based on whether they have captions. If you specify a value for this parameter, you must also set the type parameter's value to video.

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
  'videoCaption' => 'closedCaption',
  'type' => 'video'
));
```